# WordPress One Page Style Menus Scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm working on a one page template. I tried to add scrolling effect on it using Smooth Scrolling (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/), but it did not work. I couldn't find out the problem, so any help appreciated. :)

Here is the scrolling script;

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my functions.php file;

```
<?php
function theme_js(){

  wp_enqueue_script('scroll_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scroll.js', array('jquery'), '',true);

}
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_js');

?>
```

Here is my menu;

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> id="page-top" class="index">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

I'm also having a problem for highlighting each active menu item using the following js code;
Also here is the link for my project: http://modernbusiness.mburakergenc.com/

```
// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
})

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

Comment: One problem at a time please, "I'm also having a problem for highlighting...". Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Alright. I'll slow down :). Nope I do not get any errors. @Mr.Concolato

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your PHP is malformed. Try this.

```
<?php
function theme_js(){

    wp_enqueue_script('scroll_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scroll.js', array('jquery'), '',true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_js');

?>
```

Also, Wordpress loads jQuery in noconflict mode. For jQuery to be available in your scroll.js your jQuery will need to be wrapped thusly. Add these lines before the first line and after the last line in scroll.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    // Your jQuery code here. Now it is safe to be using $ to refer to jQuery.
});
```

Comment: The problem is still exists. :/

Comment: You have more than one problem. Your javascript console is showing two errors, once for scroll.js and once for contact_me.js. The error is: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.  This means that jQuery is not available to the scripts in question. You have loaded jQuery through wordpress, which means the library has been loaded in no conflict mode.  You'll need to change the wrapper code for your jQuery calls in the two aforementioned scripts. See above for the code.  I don't guarantee that that is all the problems you have :-) but that is definitely another issue.

Comment: That's just saved my life. Thanks!. There are lots of issues with the code, but I'm trying to improve the code and my skills everyday. :)